# Admin routing error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 3.2
```

In my routes.rb file, i have:

```
match :lead_billings, :to => 'admin/lead_billings#create', as: 'lead_billing'

namespace :admin do
  root to: 'statics#home'
  resources :users, :only => [] do
    resources :notes
  end
.........
```

I placed match first, to make sure it's the prioritized route for /lead_billing.

When I do rake routes, I get:

```
lead_billing    /lead_billings(.:format)    admin/lead_billings#create
```

My form (slim), has the following in it:

```
= form_for(LeadBilling.new, url: lead_billing_path) do |f|
```

But when I submit the form, I get the following:

```
Routing Error
uninitialized constant Admin::LeadBillingsController
```

And from the log file:

```
Started POST "/lead_billings" for 73.83.66.151 at 2016-11-30 21:24:10 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Admin::LeadBillingsController):
  app/middleware/catch_json_parse_errors.rb:8:in `call'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `LeadBillingsController` actually namespaced under `Admin`?

Comment: Please see edit. LeadBillingController, is not namespaced under admin. I didn't think I have to

Comment: But that's exactly what you configured: the `/` in the controller name denotes a namespace. So `admin/lead_billings` becomes `Admin::LeadBillingsController`. The path is _not_ `admin/lead_billings` but `/lead_billings`.

Answer (score 1):

The error `uninitialized constant Admin::LeadBillingsController` means that there isn't a controller with that name at that location.

Make sure you have the controller in the correct location with the correct name. Your controller would be at `app/controllers/admin/lead_billings_controller.rb` with the class name as follows.

```
class Admin::LeadBillingsController < ApplicationController
  # YOUR CODE
```

Comment: The controller is there

Comment: Add your controller to the question.